# Trouble cropping an image for a forum signature

Tags: image, inline, crop

I'm trying to take this image:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgOHf.jpg
```

(Had to comment that one cause I don't have ten rep!)

And crop it so it looks like it does here in my "signature creation box" so to speak:

[This image is cropped and sized correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24dlH.png)

I'm using this code to create the above image:

```
<img alt="" src="http://us.battle.net/static-render/us/silver-hand/111/117945967-profilemain.jpg" style="margin: -35% 0% 35%;" onclick="window.open('http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/Silver%20Hand/Robotica/advanced');" title="View Robotica's Armory" />
```

When I save it and view it on a forum post however, the image is scaled differently and appears like this:

[This image is miss-sized and cropped incorrectly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyF9H.png)

What change can I make to my code so that this image appears as intended?

Note that: Because the starting image is generated by its host-server, I cannot crop it and then upload the end-size I need. I also cannot use anything other than in-line styling for this so I cannot use div classes (afaik, I'm not certain).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

I added:

min-width: 740px;

into the img style. How I didn't think of this before, I don't know, but taking a little break and coming back to it allowed me to remember!.